# recieve a new order on restaurant app when added to database react native

Tags: react-native

hi i have a flatlist component i want to recieve a new data when added to database and a sound with that to tell the restaurant user there is a new order any help with that ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNYmG.png)

```
  <FlatList
                  data={this.state.StorePromotions}
                  style={{ padding: 2,marginBottom:100}}
                  enableEmptySections={true}
                  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                  extraData={this.state}
                  renderItem={this._renderRow1}
                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
```

Comment: Use firebase !

Comment: Sankalp Bhamare thanks for ur reply , i am using sql and my project its almost done i dont want to change that , is there another way ?

Comment: What is your backend? Php or NodeJS, or any, does it support socket.io?

Comment: my backend is php laravel , i have onesignal notification on the backend

Comment: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-messaging.html this will help!